Переключение кодировки для регулярных выражений в Notepad++
При попытке заменить верхний регистр некоторых букв русского алфавита через регулярное выражение я столкнулся с проблемой. Для русских букв оно не работает, так как, видимо, они не привязаны по регистру в кодировке программы. Можно ли как-то исправить это?
Регулярка точно работает, я проверил для английского алфавита.
Search:
<property name="([А-Я])
Replace:
<property name="\L\1
Заменить мне надо только определённые строки и проще всего будет просто прокликать через замену.

Если все равно пальцем тыкать, предлагаю записать макрос,

перед записью ctrl-f в поиске указать регулярное выражение [А-Я], закрыть окно
Нажать запись макроса
Нажать F3
Нажать Ctrl-u
Нажать остановить запись макроса
Установить курсор откуда начинать
Нажимать Ctrl-Shift-p до места окончания

